# How to avoid two variables refering to the same data? #Pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

During initializing, I tried to reduce the repeats in my code, so instead of:

```py
output=  (torch.zeros(2, 3),
          torch.zeros(2, 3))
```

I wrote:

```py
z = torch.zeros(2, 3)
output=  (z,z)
```

However, I find that the second method is wrong.

If I assign the data to variables `h,c`, any change on `h` would also be applied to `c`

```py
h,c = output
print(h,c)
h +=torch.ones(2,3)
print('-----------------')
print(h,c)
```

---

results of the test above:

```
tensor([[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]]) tensor([[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]])
-----------------
tensor([[1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.]]) tensor([[1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.]])
```

Is there a more elegent way to initialize two indenpendent variables?

Comment: Your first attempt is perfectly fine. If you *really* want to avoid repeating yourself, you can try `output = [torch.zeros(2, 3) for _ in range(2)]` but that is less readable IMO.

Comment: Like lists, tensors in pytorch are mutable data types/objects. You can think of them as the reference to an object so when you use them they will pass the reference rather than values (It helps in speeding up the operations). What you can do is either use copy() or clone() depending on what library you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that your initial line needs no modification but if you do want an alternative, consider:

```py
z = torch.zeros(2, 3)
output=  (z,z.clone())
```

The reason the other one (`output = (z,z)`) doesn't work, as you've correctly discovered is that no copy is made. You're only passing the same reference in each entry of the tuple to `z`

Answer (score -1):

Assign it in a single statement but use separate reference for each, as below:

```
h, c = output, output
```